# Query not returning CPT posts

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, wp-query

Ouch, banging my head against a wall!

I am trying to query my post type 'clips' in index.php but it's returning only posts from the default 'post'. I need some insight! What am I doing wrong?

My post type:

```
$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'supports' => $supports, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 4,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'clip',
    //'map_meta_cap' => true,
    //'capabilites' => $capabilities,
); 

register_post_type( 'clip', $args );
```

My query (index.php):

```
<?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 17, 'post_type' => array('clip'))); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<ul id="clips" class="clearfix reset">

  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <li>
      <?php the_title();?><br><?php the_permalink(); ?>
      <a id="post-<?php the_id(); ?>" class="videolink" title="Click to view" href="">
      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
         the_post_thumbnail(); 
        } else { 
        echo "No thumbnail"; 
        } ?></a>
    </li>

   <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>


    <?php else: ?>

        <p>Sorry, but this content is not available.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Note there are no other loops in the template file.

Comment: On what context are you registering your post type? functions.php, in a plugin file? Which action are you using to call these functions?

Comment: On closer inspection ANY post apart from type 'post' is failing to return anything using standard functions. Woah! Gotta find out what's going on there. Back soon.

Comment: functions.php has an include to the file with the code. Action is 'init'. How might that affect the output?

Comment: Don't know what it was and unfortunately I don't have time to look deeper but a clean db fixed the issue. :-/

Comment: It seems like you forgot to post the full function of your `register_post_type` or else that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and posted the solution here:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/role-scoper-updating-query_posts

query_posts causes the main WP_Query to be discarded. That may or may not be the behavior you want. If no, you need to update WP_Query, then you could update your functions.php file to include a register filter that displays your content types as part of WP_Query (see code at URL above). If yes, you don't care about WP_Query, then I ran my query_posts after have_posts with this code in my index.php file:

```
    query_posts(array('post_type' => array('post', 'article', 'document', 'faq', 'video')));
```

Comment: Yes, yes! that makes sense! Thanks for the insight!