# Query does not return content

Tags: query, the-content, post-content

Working on updating an old WP site developed for WordPress 2.0 and have a post (page) query that does not return the "post_content" data.

Here is said query:

```
$the_query = query_posts('post_type=page&post_parent=50&post_status=publish&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&posts_per_page=100');
```

And the returned object (one of them):

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 249
        [post_title] => John Doe
        [link_link] => 1
        [no_follow_link] => 0
        [redirect_url] => 
        [target_blank] => 0
        [post_status] => publish
        [post_name] => john-do
        [post_parent] => 50
        [guid] => http://beta.mysite.org/
        [post_type] => page
        [filter] => raw
    )
```

Notably this is missing the post_content. Which is kind of a big deal. Any ideas? I don't think it's a memory limit issue. I've tried many different work-arounds. Suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: See if this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27369/17968) could help

Comment: disable all plugins, to see if any of them is messing up with the content filter.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) here, but rather [**`WP_Query()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query). (Search WPSE for `query_posts` if you want to know wy.)

```
<?php
$custom_query_args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => '50',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '100'
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

// To see the contents of the $custom_query object
var_dump( $custom_query );
?>
```

### Edit

> No dice. Same result.

The query is returning exactly what it is intended to return. In order to access the `$post` data, you need to **set up the Loop**:

```
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post() );

    // The $post variable is now available, 
    // so you can access the post content, either as
    // $post->post_content or as the_content()

endwhile; endif;
```

So, I'm guessing your problem is that you're not setting up the Loop.

Comment: No dice. Same result.

Comment: What, exactly, does the `var_dump()` return?